# wso2 esb proxy registry persistence

Tags: registry, wso2, esb

I have configured WSO2 ESB to listen from registry instead of filesystem. However, proxy services are still getting saved into filesystem and cannot be searched from WSO2 Greg.
Please advise

Answer (score 0):

You can find the documentation related to using the registry with the ESB here [1]. Please provide more information is you still get the same results after following the documentation.

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Registry